# Slide down and fix the header

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm sitting here and creating my own little website. 
For my first responsive layout i want to slide down my header after 200px of scrolling and fix it.

I have this code here:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  var header = $('header'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 200) header.addClass('fixed');
  else header.removeClass('fixed');
});
```

for fixing the header after 200px. But this solution is a little bit to hard. 
Hope you can help me. Thanks for support.

Comment: What do you by 'this solution is a little bit too hard'? Does it work? Do you mean you don't know how to implement it?

Comment: I mean that the header apears directly and not fading in or slides down. It's difficult for me to explain it in english. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be forgetting to add the class to your header object.  If you have a div with class='header', then your variable declaration should be:

```
var header = $('.header'),
```

Here is a [link to a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Suiname/aforqt8p/2/) with an example of this code working.

Comment: Good catch -- I missed that in my answer +1

Comment: No, i' using <header> </header> so this was correct and your solution looks like mine. After some scrolling the header (in your case .header) appears. And there is my problem. i want that the header oder .header slides down from top after 200px of scrolling and fixed.

Comment: I see, so you want an animation to slide the header down and then fix it?

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a start. *Note the addition of a boolean variable to limit the number of times the class is added/removed.*

```
//javascript:
//Define variables outside the scroll function
var win = $(window), header = $('header'), isDown = false;

win.scroll(function(){
  //This function fires thousands of times, so limit that
    scrollpos = win.scrollTop();
  if ( !isDown && scrollpos >= 200){
    header.addClass('fixed');
    isDown = true;
  }else if ( isDown && scrollpos < 200)
    header.removeClass('fixed');
    isDown = false;
  }
}); //END window.scroll


<!-- HTML -->
<!-- Remember to add the jQuery library (just above `</body>` in document) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but this ones doesnt work?!

Comment: Please don't say 'doesn't work'. That is not good debugging. What _does_ it do?

Comment: You are right Tim, thats not very helpful.
But i see nothing. I added the code into my <head> and when i scroll down there is no fixed header or anything else.